# Visual Studio Standard Style as CSS

Tags: css, visual-studio, styles, copy-paste

I'm searching for the correct style to configure [CopySourceAsHtml](http://copysourceashtml.codeplex.com/) to change my [Selenitic](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/selenitic) style to default Visual Studio style when I copy and paste it to e.g. an e-mail. Does anybody know what CSS style(s) I need to use to set it up correctly?

When I copy & paste source code an e-mail I get a dark background. If I set it to white it will show all text in light colours which are hard to read. So I need to change the complete style.

Comment: http://studiostyl.es/schemes/default

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. It needs to be as CSS. Because you can change the CSS style in the tools options.

Comment: You could write it yourself?

Comment: Please feel free to help me out with this. I don't know anything about CSS and thought there will be a CSS code already.

Answer (score 0):

How does your plugin expect the CSS to look like? If you open the theme I referred to in the comments above in a text editor you'll see a lot of lines like this:

```
<Item Name="outlining.collapsehintadornment" Foreground="0x00E8DDD7" Background="0x00FAF7F6" BoldFont="No"/>
```

Now since I don't know how exactly your plugin is expecting the CSS I will go ahead and give an example of what this **might** look like in CSS:

```
.outlining-collapsehintadornment
{
    color: #D7DDE8;
    background-color: #F6F7FA;
}
```

Or:

```
<Item Name="String" Foreground="0x001515A3" Background="0x02000000" BoldFont="No"/>
```

Becomes

```
.String
{
    color: #A31515; 
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

How did I get this?

Visual Studio settings file save color codes as "code hex" values. And they use BGR instead of RGB. This means that you can convert this VS color hexes very simple to HTML color hexes. And since HTML uses RGB don't forget to invert the code. So for example:
0x00E8DDD7. Replace the 0x00 (sometimes this may be 0x02) with a #. And then swap the first 2 and the last 2 characters (BGR to RGB). So you get #E8DDD7 = #D7DDE8. And of course "Foreground" is text-color and "Background" is background-color...If your plugin supports it you might even consider to write `font-size: bold` if you see `BoldFont="Yes"` in your XML.

Summarized: Open the VSSettings file I referred to in my comment above in a texteditor. Then convert everything to CSS. Write a simple program to do this, or do it by hand, whatever you prefer. Just remember that this is just an example of what it might look like. I don't know what "CopySourceAsHtml" is expecting your CSS to look like.